# combobox from a text file reading only one word

Tags: c#

I have a text file that a combobox is picking up data from. My problem is that the box is only taking the first word of the line and not actually the whole line (space separated line)

my code is the following:

```
{   
    String path1 = "C:\\Support\\Queue.txt";
    System.IO.StreamReader sr1 = new System.IO.StreamReader(path1);
    string[] allLine1 = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
    for (int i = 0; i >= allLine1.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (allLine1[i] == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            string[] item1 = allLine1[i].Split(new char[]
            {
            });
            comboBox2.Items.Add(item1[1]);
```

Comment: Not really sure what your intended behavior is

Comment: If you want the whole line why do you split it and add the 'second' word in that line then?

Comment: sorry guys, not an expert here but all I want is to have a sentence to show on each line, the text file shows different sentences in each line and I want each entry in the combo box to show the full sentence instead of the first word.

Comment: by the way, this line _for (int i = 0; i >= allLine1.Length - 1; i++)_ makes no sense, probably it should be _for (int i = 0; i < allLine1.Length; i++)_

Comment: thank you for that steve, but unfortunately that gives an error when changed, I got the code from an online tutorial, I am no expert, just trying to do a little app that will help automating things

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are only adding the first word of the line to the combobox when you call `item1[1]`

Your else statement should be more like

```
else
{
  comboBox2.Items.Add(allLine1[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use clean approach you will never get confuse, your code should be some thing like

```
string path1 = "C:\\Support\\Queue.txt";
            if (File.Exists(path1))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(path1))
                {
                    string[] allLine1 = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
                    foreach (var item in allLine1)
                    {
                        comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
```